# Google Maps like Map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

Ive seen people using the google maps interface for their own maps. Does anyone know if this is legal and how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

This is perfectly legal. Google even [exposes an API for this](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/index.html).

You can also find a tutorial here: [link](http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 4):

It is legal (and encouraged!)

The main limitation is that the application using Google Maps must be freely available.  If you want to use them in a for-pay application, you have to pay for a license.  See the collection of FAQs following on from here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_commercial

Comment: What if there are some purchasable "bonus-items" but the app itself is totally free?

Comment: Not exactly. You can sell an iOS app which uses a Google Map without buying a license. But for web apps, you could be right though.

Comment: @kojoma: Looking at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#tos_commercial I think you might be OK, but you'd need to read the license agreement and possibly talk to Google about it.

Answer (score 0):

Google code playground is a good place to start learning

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3